# Is it possible to force ribbon commands for an Office.JS add-in to present in highDensityLayout by default using the manifest file?

Tags: office-js

In MS Word, ribbon icons can be forced to the smaller size and the command label hidden in the settings.  I see it can also be done by setting highDensityLayout="true" for the corresponding xml element in the customization file.  Can this be done for office.JS add-in commands by way of the manifest file?  I haven't seen any examples of add-ins that have done this, and could not find anything in the Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not currently possible. There is no granular control over how add-in commands are displayed, the platform controls it depending on the available real state. You can check [user voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/search?filter=merged&query=ribbon) and vote/suggest the idea. Thanks.